# Angular2 detect if a user is already logged in from another computer

Tags: angular

What am trying to achieve is that i would like when a user attempts to login in my web app I would like to check and see if he is logged in from another computer and if he is, automatically login him out from the other computer.

So in my login component:

```
login(){
   //here check if user is already logged in in another location
  //not sure how to implement this.
}
```

How do I implement such functionality

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a client-side framework. It would have not have the ability to check whether the user is logged in to another computer.

If you wanted to store that information somewhere, Angular could use Http to retrieve whether the user is logged in.

For example:

- User logs into machine 1.
- That fact is stored in a database on a server somewhere.
- User logs into machine 2.
- Angular uses Http to call the server and check whether the user is already logged in.

Comment: I like to add another point that client-side framework is stateless and it depends on the service(SOA)

Comment: How do you detect that the user has logged out?

Comment: Is this a question to me or to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Client side frameworks like angular are stateless. This issue has to be dealt in the back end. In your back make a Map(datastructure based on key/value pair) of session id and user id.

You put entries to this Map on every successful login. When you are writing entry to the Map, make a check, to see if any other session id is already using this user id. If it is there in the Map, check if the session id is still active. If it is not active, allow the login, and delete the old sessionID. If it is active, then you can do what you desire to do in this situation.

If you are using Java in the backend, then you can use HashMap to put key value pair of session id and user id.

If you are using Node.js then check out this link about Map
[HashMap in Node JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap)